# funcion de javaScript obtener objetos con array adentro

Tags: javascript, arraylist

tengo que  obtener un Objeto en que las claves sean los nombres de los campos y los valores un arreglo con los ruts de sus administradores ordenados alfabéticamente por nombre.

estos son los array :

```
    const farms = [
        { id: 1, name: 'AGRICOLA SANTA ANA' },
        { id: 2, name: 'VINA SANTA PAULA' },
        { id: 3, name: 'FORESTAL Y AGRICOLA LO ENCINA' }
    ];
    const paddockManagers = [
        { id: 1, taxNumber: '132254524', name: 'JUAN TAPIA BURGOS' },
        { id: 2, taxNumber: '143618668', name: 'EFRAIN SOTO VERA' },
        { id: 3, taxNumber: '78903228', name: 'CARLOS PEREZ GONZALEZ' },
        { id: 4, taxNumber: '176812737', name: 'ANDRES VIÑALES CIENFUEGOS' },
        { id: 5, taxNumber: '216352696', name: 'OSCAR PEREZ ZUÑIGA' },
        { id: 6, taxNumber: '78684747', name: 'JOAQUIN ANDRADE SANDOVAL' }
    ];
```

esta es la funcion que hice :

```
   function farmManagerNames() {
        var objectManager = {}
        for (let farm in farms) {
            let framName = farms.filter((paddockManagers) => {
                return paddockManagers.nameFarm === farms[farm].name
            }).map(paddockManagers => paddockManagers.name).sort()

            let valorUnico = Array.from(new Set(framName));
            let contenedor = []
            for (let i = 0; i < valorUnico.length; i++) {
                contenedor.push(valorUnico[i])
            }
            objectManager[farms[farm].name] = contenedo
            
        }
        return objectManager
    }
    console.log(farmManagerNames())
```

pero me  devuelve los array vacios:

```
   Object
  AGRICOLA SANTA ANA: []
  FORESTAL Y AGRICOLA LO ENCINA: []
  VINA SANTA PAULA: []
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

me podrian indicar que es lo q me esta faltando en la función para poder colocar los ruts dentro de los array

Comment: Te está faltando información, ahi tenes una lista de farms, y una lista de managers, pero te está faltando una lista que los relacione entre si.